# Does SLX cloud allow custom libraries?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

newbie here. I'm trying SLX for a small project in C++ but am not sure whether their cloud application lets me install the custom libraries I need to compile my project. I'm willing to download their desktop version if I HAVE to, but is there a way to do this within my workspace in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying our cloud platform! I am the product manager of [SLX.cloud](https://slx.cloud) (a free online version of our multicore optimization tools), so if you have any further questions you can ask me directly. You can find my contact details in my profile.

Currently, there are two ways to install your own software within a workspace. I would suggest installing it temporarily first to see if everything works out out and then move to a permanent installation.

## 1. Temporary Installation

Through the terminal within the IDE you have full access the to underlying docker container. Our image is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so you can install software via `sudo apt-get` just like on your local computer.

[image]

One note though: everytime a workspace is started and stopped, [SLX.cloud](https://slx.cloud) will fetch the docker image again. Therefore all change outside the `/project` folder will be lost.

## 2. Permanent Installation

To permanently install software, you can [create](https://slx.cloud/dashboard/#/create-project) a custom stack or adjust the workspace configuration. To do so, go to `Dashboard -> Create Workspace -> Create New Workspace from stack -> Stack Authoring`.
Here you can create a custom docker image and provide software to install on startup. To do so, just add the following configuration (`libopencv-dev` in this example):

```
FROM silexica/tools:latest

RUN sudo apt-get update \
&& sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev \
&& sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Here we specify to install `libopencv-dev` during startup and it will be available within the workspace.

[image]

If you are familiar with docker, you can of course also create a docker image based on `silexica/tools:latest` and install the necessary software on top of it. You just need to provide your docker image the same way above via the `FROM <your/docker:image>` command and you can skip the `RUN` command.

After that, you can start your customized workspace by clicking `Create`.